# MySQL - How to join and get data from these three tables?

Tags: mysql

I have the following three tables:

**Store Table**

```
+----------+------------+
| STORE_ID | STORE_NAME |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | Shop 1     |
|        2 | Shop 2     |
|        3 | Shop 3     |
+----------+------------+
```

**Employee Table**

```
+--------+------------+----------+---------+
| EMP_NO | MANAGER_NO | EMP_NAME | STORE_ID |
+--------+------------+----------+---------+
|   3465 |       4356 | A Smith  |       1 |
|   4356 |            | M Jones  |       2 |
|   7645 |       4356 | J Adam   |       3 |
+--------+------------+----------+---------+
```

**Payment Table**

```
+------------+------------+-------+--------+----------+
| PAYMENT_ID |    DATE    | TOTAL | EMP_NO | STORE_ID |
+------------+------------+-------+--------+----------+
|          1 | 01/01/2016 | 20.00 |   7645 |        3 |
|          2 | 10/02/2016 | 10.00 |   3465 |        1 |
|          3 | 15/03/2016 | 5.00  |   3465 |        1 |
|          4 | 25/04/2016 | 50.00 |   7645 |        3 |
|          5 | 30/05/2016 | 35.00 |   7645 |        3 |
+------------+------------+-------+--------+----------+
```

Given the tables above how can i create view tables showing sales figures for each of the 3 stores.

Each table needs to display the following:

- Store name, name of store manager, name of top salesperson in that store and the number of sales for this person.

I have currently done the following but am completely stuck. I am fairly new to SQL and have used join in the past but cant seem to figure it out for this.

```
SELECT  s.store_id AS "Store Name",
    e1.manager_no AS "Manager Name",    
    e2.emp_name AS "Salesperson",   
    SUM(p.total) AS "Sales Value"
FROM store_table s
JOIN
```

Comment: You should start looking for `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.syntax. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Was it helpful my answer???

Comment: @YanetPedraza Not really. I cant seem to get it to return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify this example according to your case, but I think it could be like this:

```
  SELECT  s.store_id AS "Store Name",
        e.manager_no AS "Manager Name",    
        e.emp_name AS "Salesperson",   
        SUM(p.total) AS "Sales Value"
    FROM store_table s
    INNER JOIN employee_table AS e
        ON s.STORE_ID = e.STORE_ID 
    INNER JOIN payment_table AS p
        ON s.STORE_ID = p.STORE_ID
```